# Can't run individual Cucumber scenarios using TestNG test runner

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Is there anyway to run cucumber scenarios using the TestNG runner by right clicking individual scenarios in the feature files rather than using the command file or running the TestNG runner file directly?

I'm using Intellij to run cucumber scenarios in a maven testing framework. In the POM.xml file I have the Surefire plugin referencing the testNG.xml file which points to the TestNG runner class.

When I run "mvn test" from terminal it calls the TestNG testrunner,but when I right click on the scenario in the feature file to select run, it runs the io.cucumber.core.cli.main class that calls the io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner class testrunner.

I can't edit Run/Debug configuration to use the TestNG runner because the TestNG runner doesn't have a Main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybone runs into the same issue, I managed to get around the issue by creating another class with a main method and calling the mvn command to run the test from there.  something like this:

```
String mvnCommand = "mvn test ";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", mvnCommand + args);
processBuilder.start();
```

Not sure if there's a better solution, but I can't seem to find any other option with Cucumber for Java plugin.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a runner class and add tags you need into CucumberOptions.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"}, strict = true, tags = {"@yourTag"})
public class RunTestNGTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I have.  The problem is that I can only trigger the test from the runner class itself.  When I right click the scenario itself in the feature file, it runs the CLI runner and not the custom runner class file in the project.

Comment: Ah, got it. You want to run it via green button. But it creates a Run Configuration in Intellij (I believe with Cucumber plugin), yes, with CLI, but you can Run and Debug it as other types of configurations, no?

Comment: Yes.  It runs successfully through the CLI.  The io.core.cli.main main method create a io.core.runner.Runner class test runner.   

I'm only able to use the custom test runner class if I run the tests directly from there.